# Trigger.IO: Hello world app does not start on Android API Level 10

Tags: trigger.io

I'm running into a strange problem when trying to start a freshly created app (no code changes) on Android API Level 10. When starting the app on the emulator it goes into a endless loop with the trigger.io startup logo blinking after each loop. I see the following output in the console:

```
[   INFO] I/Forge   (  328): Loading initial page in webview.
[   INFO] I/Forge   (  328): Application in focus, resuming webview.
[   INFO] D/Forge   (  328): Returning event: {"event":"internal.connectionState
Change","params":{"wifi":false,"connected":true}}
[   INFO] I/Forge   (  344): Loading initial page in webview.
[   INFO] I/Forge   (  344): Application in focus, resuming webview.
[   INFO] D/Forge   (  344): Returning event: {"event":"internal.connectionState
Change","params":{"wifi":false,"connected":true}}
[   INFO] I/Forge   (  356): Loading initial page in webview.
[   INFO] I/Forge   (  356): Application in focus, resuming webview.
[   INFO] D/Forge   (  356): Returning event: {"event":"internal.connectionState
Change","params":{"wifi":false,"connected":true}}
```

Strangely enough it works well on lower and higher API Levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hrmpf! A classic case of RTFM!

From the docs:

> Important There is a bug in the Android 2.3 emulator that will render
>   your apps unusable: if you manage your own Android AVD you must use an
>   Android 2.2 level AVD.